# Unique triggering of window.requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm using the function window.requestAnimationFrame.

I don't know why, but instead of continuous triggering, it is firing just once when I click 'Play'

The html is

```
<button id='play'>Play</button>
<button id='pause'>Pause</button>
```

The code in coffeeScript

```
class Counter
  i:0
  init: () ->
    $('#play').click @fire.bind(@)
    $('#pause').click @unfire.bind(@)
  fire:() ->
    window.requestAnimationFrame @update.bind(@)
  unfire:() ->
    window.cancelAnimationFrame @update.bind(@)
  update: () ->
    $('h1').remove()
    $('<h1></h1>').appendTo 'body'
    $('h1').text @i
    @i++

tick = new Counter()
tick.init()
```

The script in the codepen: http://codepen.io/helloncanella/pen/mJrwwP?editors=101

Comment: But what do you want? If you want that "counter" will fire again and again then inside update function call it again as: requestAnimationFrame(update)

Comment: I've seen the error 2 minutes ago. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I've forgotten to call window.requestAnimationFrame @update.bind(@) inside update function

Answer (score 0):

```
class Banana
  i:0
  animation: null

  init: () ->
    $('#play').click @fire.bind(@)
    $('#pause').click @unfire.bind(@)

    console.log @fire
  fire:() ->
    @animation = requestAnimationFrame(@update.bind(@))
  unfire:() ->
    cancelAnimationFrame(@animation)
  update: () ->
    $('h1').text @i
    $('<h1></h1>').appendTo 'body'
    @i++
    @animation = requestAnimationFrame(@update.bind(@))

fruit = new Banana()
fruit.init()
```